# Swift2: Correct way to initialise UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFMutableDictionary>?> parameter to pass to IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties

Tags: macos, swift, swift2, iokit

Ok, so in Swift 2, the definition for `IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties` is

```
func IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(entry: io_registry_entry_t, _ properties: UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFMutableDictionary>?>, _ allocator: CFAllocator!, _ options: IOOptionBits) -> kern_return_t
```

I can do

```
var dict: UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFMutableDictionary>?> = nil
kr = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(box as io_registry_entry_t, dict, kCFAllocatorDefault, nilOptions)
```

which compiles and runs. Of course it crashes when it executes the `IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties` because `dict` is initialised to `nil`. My question is how to initialise `dict` to a non-nil value? I've tried various approaches without success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A parameter of the type

```
UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFMutableDictionary>?>
```

means that you have to pass a variable of the type

```
Unmanaged<CFMutableDictionary>?
```

as an inout-argument with `&`. On success, you can unwrap the optional
(with optional binding),
convert the unmanaged object to a managed object with
`takeRetainedValue()`, and finally (if you want), cast the `CFMutableDictionary` to `NSDictionary`.

Example:

```
var props : Unmanaged<CFMutableDictionary>?
if IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(entry, &props, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0) == KERN_SUCCESS {
    if let props = props {
        let dict = props.takeRetainedValue() as NSDictionary
        print(dict)
    }
}
```